# Change language with next-i18next library without change the locale in the router

Tags: typescript, next.js, internationalization, react-i18next, next-i18next

I have a "problem". I want to implement the **i18n** in my **Next.js** web app, using this library [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next). It is working if I change the route with the correct locale, like so **localhost:3000/en --> localhost:3000/it**, however the result tha I would like to obtain is to change the language without changing the route. Basically I would like to not use the feature **Internationalized Routing** of Next.js with the implementation of **i18n**. I'm new in the environment of Next.js.
Thanks in advance for the responses